# Sent mail/login log for roundcube webmail

Tags: security, email, logging, roundcube

Does roundcube webmail have a log for logins, or for sent mail? I searched everywhere but could only located the "error log" directory in roundcube, not one for logins or for sent mail. I'm trying to locate possible account theft, and seeing the IP addresses used to login to the email account recently would help track the possible thief.

Answer (score 1):

I found the sent-mail log file at :

> roundcube dir/logs/sendmail

It contains a long list of sent email logs, and the IP address of the sender as well. This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

That log is controlled with config/main.inc.php directive:

```
// Log sent messages to <log_dir>/sendmail or to syslog
$rcmail_config['smtp_log'] = true;
```